# Pipe Python output to Java Program

Tags: java, python, bash

How do I go about piping the output of a python program as an argument for a Java program?

I have the following code:

Python (test.py):

```
print("Hello There")
```

Java (test.java):

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(String value : args) {
      System.out.println(value);
    }
  }
}
```

In my command line I'm executing the following:

```
python test.py | java Test
```

I'm getting the following error:

BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Can anyone explain why this is happening and what would be a good way of fixing it? Many thanks :)

Comment: Your input is available to be read from `System.in`, it's not in `args`.

Comment: ...so, from the perspective of the Python program, the pipe on its stdout is broken because the Java program exits without ever reading from the other side of it.